# ReactJS DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': MouseEvent object could not be cloned

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do my first ReactApp and I got the DataCloneError error.

I have the following code:

```
postsToShow.map((post, id)=>
   <ul key={id}>
        {post.title}
        <button onClick={(post)=>showPost(post)}>Show post</button>
    </ul>
    )
```

and I want to trigger the method showPost when the button is clicked.

This is the showPost method:

```
  const showPost=(post)=>
{
    history.push({
        pathname: '/showCurrentPost',
        state: {post: post}
    })}
```

I got this error DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': MouseEvent object could not be cloned and I don't have any ideas how to fix it.

I would be very grateful if you culd help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Any data stored in the history needs to be serialized. Objects, arrays, strings, and numbers can be serialized, but most other objects, including `MouseEvent` objects can't be. In this case, your `post` object contains a `MouseEvent` object.

In this case, you did not mean to even store the event, so you can fix your code like this:

```
<button onClick={(ev)=>showPost(post)}>Show post</button>
```

That way you don't hide the `post` variable form the enclosing scope, and don't replace it with an event object.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to remove/rename argument inside anonymous function
posts

```
ToShow.map((post, id)=>
   <ul key={id}>
        {post.title}
        <button onClick={(e)=>showPost(post)}>Show post</button>
    </ul>
    )
```

As the docs says: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers

You are renaming post in your render function scope from original post to synteticEventHandler.